# How to get the value of a textbox from an optionalblock from jelly to java?

Tags: java, xml, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I just started to code with Jelly and I have a question :
I want to print the value I wrote in the textbox. The text box is in a optionalblock I checked. But when I want to print its value, it prints "null". Ithink that the value is not saved or maybe I have to check if the checbox is checked...
Here are my codes and thanks for helping

config.jelly

```
<f:block>
    <table>
        <f:optionalBlock name="toRemote" title="Remote">
            <f:entry title="Full parameter name">
                <f:textbox name="parameter_name" value="${it.parameter_name}"/>
            </f:entry>
        </f:optionalBlock>
    </table>
</f:block>
```

HelloWorldBuilder.java

```
public class HelloWorldBuilder extends Builder {

    private final String parameter_name;

    /**
     * This annotation tells Hudson to call this constructor, with
     * values from the configuration form page with matching parameter names.
     */
    @DataBoundConstructor
    public HelloWorldBuilder(String parameter_name) {
        this.parameter_name = parameter_name;
    }

    /**
     * We'll use this from the <tt>config.jelly</tt>.
     */
    public String getParameter_ame() {
        return parameter_name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean perform(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) throws IOException {
        // this is where you 'build' the project
        // since this is a dummy, we just say 'hello world' and call that a build

        listener.getLogger().println("Parameter name = " + parameter_name + "!");
        build.save();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: i see a typo `public String getParameter_ame() {` should be `public String getParameter_name() {`. not sure how relevant that is in this case however.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I fixed it after asking this question. But it still DOESN'T work...